# Know what timezone is closest to a given time in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, algorithm, timezone, utc

What is the best way to know what UTC timezone has, let's say, 7:00 AM right now. Or find the one that is closest.

One way would be to have an array of all the timezones (there are only 39, not a big number), loop through them, find the one with least difference.

But, I'm looking for a better solution. Is there?

Comment: What other search techniques do you know for a sorted list, other than linear search?

Comment: Yeah. Is that the only way? Searching algos. I was thinking maybe there was a more native way using Date() in JS.

Comment: Careful with assumptions there...  The [TZDB list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) currently has 384 distinct zone entries...   You should also read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: But, I'm more worried about the UTC offset. Coz, these timezones are divided into 39 offsets. Right?